# Get the maximum number of consecutive zeros SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table. The months columns represent the number of orders each customer has placed. I want to calculate the maximum number of consecutive zeros.

| customer_id | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

so the result table would be:

| customer_id | cons_zeros |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

I know there is a window function like that can tackle consecutive 0s for rows but am unsure how to do it for columns.

Comment: Step 1. Normalise your schema; a database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest unpivoting, treating this as a gaps-and-islands problem, and then reaggregating:

```
select customerid,
       max(case when val = 0 then cnt else 0 end) as max_zeros
from (select customerid, val, (n - seqnum), count(*) as cnt
      from (select cn.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by customerid, val order by n) as seqnum
            from (select customerid, 1 as n, jan as val from t union all
                  select customerid, 2 as n, feb as val from t union all
                  select customerid, 3 as n, mar as val from t union all
                  select customerid, 4 as n, apr as val from t union all
                  select customerid, 5 as n, may as val from t union all
                  select customerid, 6 as n, jun as val from t 
                 ) cn
           ) cn
      group by customerid, val, (n - seqnum)
     ) cn
group by customerid;
```